# How to map a folder in MsBuild for copying?

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, ckeditor

I'm using [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/) for a lot of my ASP.NET Core projects.

Thus I decided to centralize it somewhere and reuse it across projects.

Let's say I have these file system hierarchy:

- Base
- Project1
- Project2
- Project3
- ...

I have put `ckeditor` in `Base` folder.

Now I want to include it in each project's `.csproj` file. I know I can use this code snippet:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="..\Base\CkEditor\**\*.*">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

But this always copies everything to the output's root directory.

I need to be able to specify the target path, or the output path for copying, per project.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContentWithTargetPath` property and set its `TargetPath` attribute to specify the path to the output directory.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ContentWithTargetPath
          Include="..\Base\CkEditor\**\*.*"
          CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"
          TargetPath="ckeditor\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

### References

- https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2949